# Site becomes inaccessible due to PHP-FPM listen queue, CPU touches 100%

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, wordpress, fastcgi

I've been racking my brains apart trying to solve this issue that comes up randomly every few hours on my production server hosting a single Wordpress blog (with decent traffic: 2000 users realtime on average days, 5000+ on good days, pageviews per minute varies from 300 to 700+).

I use Newrelic to monitor performance and I've noticed a peculiar thing:

Every few hours (randomly), the PHP-FPM pool status goes something like below (real status taken yesterday)

```
pool:                 www
process manager:      static
start time:           02/Jan/2017:05:03:16 -0500
start since:          27290
accepted conn:        1107594
listen queue:         777
max listen queue:     794
listen queue len:     40000
idle processes:       0
active processes:     100
total processes:      100
max active processes: 101
max children reached: 0
slow requests:        0
```

Restarting `PHP-FPM` and `nginx` solves the issue but it happens again in a couple of hours. Any help is appreciated. Please guide me.

---

Server setup:

```
DigitalOcean 48GB Memory
16 Core Processor
480GB SSD Disk
```

PHP-FPM pool setting:

```
pm = static
pm.max_children = 100
pm.max_requests = 5000
```

nginx config:

```
worker_processes  32;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;
events {
    worker_connections  40000;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}
```

I'm also using `xcache`, `varnish` with `W3TC` on Wordpress. (also have Cloudflare)

sysctl.conf:

```
# Increase size of file handles and inode cache
fs.file-max = 2097152

# Do less swapping
vm.swappiness = 10
vm.dirty_ratio = 60
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 2

### GENERAL NETWORK SECURITY OPTIONS ###

# Number of times SYNACKs for passive TCP connection.
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 2

# Allowed local port range
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 2000 65535

# Protect Against TCP Time-Wait
net.ipv4.tcp_rfc1337 = 1

# Decrease the time default value for tcp_fin_timeout connection
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 15

# Decrease the time default value for connections to keep alive
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 300
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 5
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 15

### TUNING NETWORK PERFORMANCE ###

# Default Socket Receive Buffer
net.core.rmem_default = 31457280

# Maximum Socket Receive Buffer
net.core.rmem_max = 12582912

# Default Socket Send Buffer
net.core.wmem_default = 31457280

# Maximum Socket Send Buffer
net.core.wmem_max = 12582912

# Increase number of incoming connections
net.core.somaxconn = 40000

# Increase number of incoming connections backlog
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 65536

# Increase the maximum amount of option memory buffers
net.core.optmem_max = 25165824

# Increase the maximum total buffer-space allocatable
# This is measured in units of pages (4096 bytes)
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 65536 131072 262144
net.ipv4.udp_mem = 65536 131072 262144

# Increase the read-buffer space allocatable
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem= 10240 87380 12582912
net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min = 16384

# Increase the write-buffer-space allocatable
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem= 10240 87380 12582912
net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min = 16384

# Increase the tcp-time-wait buckets pool size to prevent simple DOS attacks
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 1440000
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
```

Comment: Why do you have PHP `pm.max_children` set so low?

Comment: @MichaelHampton after reading up a lot of answers on Stackoverflow and ServerFault and a few blogs, I realized that most people recommend `max_children` to be within 5 to 50. But I still wasn't convinced and pumped up the number to 100. I had always doubted it, what do you recommend?

Comment: Maybe you could give it a shot and see if it's helping ? @MichaelHampton is probably right on that !

Comment: You read recommendations for people who had very small sites on very small hardware. This is not you. I suggest reading _your own previous posts_ for starters.

Comment: Yeah, @MichaelHampton you're right. I've been trying to fix this since forever now. I can see questions from 2013 and more or less it's the same issue. 3 years down the line, I've fixed most of it, but this intermittent issue still persist. Having said that, I can see that now traffic is around `1800` realtime and process stats are `idle processes:       95
active processes:     5
total processes:      100`. It's only when the queue keeps on piling, I need more processes. So should I put it at around say 500 or 1000? Or do you suggest higher?

Comment: Raise it until it's enough. You'll know when it's enough because the problem doesn't happen anymore.

Comment: Another alternative is to look at average memory consumption per PHP worker process and divide your maximum memory by the memory consumption and use that as the number of `max_children`.

Comment: @LittleLebowski I know this post is so old, but did you eventually came to a conclusion regarding your problem? Thanks.